# Git clone error after OS X Mountain Lion update

Tags: macos, git

I just updated my MBP to OSX 10.8 and am trying to start a new project with brunch.io which by default uses coffeescript and I prefer javascript so I need to clone the simple js skeleton. So something like this:

```
brunch new <someprojectname> --skeleton https://github.com/brunch/simple-js-skeleton.git
```

Which is what I have used previously and it worked fine. But today I am getting the following error:

```
error: Git clone error: /bin/sh: git: command not found
```

I really don't know how to fix this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is caused by not having git installed. Your previous installation was probably lost in the update (don't worry, your repos will still be intact).

You can download git from its official page, [here](http://git-scm.com/download/mac).

If you're a member of an Apple developer program you can also install git by installing the Xcode command line tools, found in the Downloads tab of Xcode's preferences.

Comment: Thanks! it worked for me by installing the Command line tools from the Xcode.